# yii framework PHP User Error - The directory is not writable by the Web process

Tags: apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, yii

I am facing an issue with YII Framework on Server 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

PHP Version:

```
# php -v
```

Output:

```
PHP 7.0.5 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2016 13:08:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Permission:

```
#chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/backend/web/assets
```

Error:

```
PHP User Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/html/backend/web/assets' 

in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php:213
```

Solutions Already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482597/yii2-the-directory-is-not-writable-by-the-web-process-frontend-web-assets

```
$ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep
```

Output:

```
apache   14041 14040  0 06:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   14042 14040  0 06:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   14043 14040  0 06:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   14044 14040  0 06:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   14045 14040  0 06:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   14046 14040  0 06:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

The same thing working fine with Centos, Ubuntu and other OSes but on Red Hat problem is still there.

Comment: Does the error still occur if you suspend the `httpd` service before running `chmod`?

Comment: Yes Burgi the error still occurring.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, the command you have typed is:

```
#chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/backend/web/assets
```

Since you want to change the permission of that folder, you need to have a elevated user privileges. Hence append **sudo** before your query to provide the elevated user privileges to the command and to change the directory permissions